# how to change usestate of state variable in if condition?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to change the usestate of quizFinished to true after satisfying the condition in the handleAnswerClick() function. This is the code below .

Note : I am learning react from Codedamn React 18 Video 29

````
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
    // Define a state variable here to track question status

    const [quizFinished, setQuizFinished] = useState(false)
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)

    
    function handleAnswerClick() {
        // Check if the quiz is over here
        if (currentIndex === questions.length) {
           setQuizFinished(quizFinished=true) 
        }
        else {
            setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
        }         


        // If yes, set the quizFinished variable to true
        

        // If no, increment the current index like always
        
    }

    ```

Their is some HTML code below that is in the tutorial. The Tutorial is free.
````

Comment: `setQuizFinished(true)` instead of `setQuizFinished(quizFinished=true)`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Upvoted the question on account of you actually specifying the precise video you're watching :)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `true` to `setQuizFinished`:

```
setQuizFinished(true)
```

However, since `quizFinished` is derived from `currentIndex` using a state is redundant. Just compute it on each render:

```
export default function App() {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)
    
  const quizFinished = currentIndex === questions.length
    
  function handleAnswerClick() {
    if(!quizFinished) {
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex => currentIndex + 1);
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Just pass true to setQuizFinished
2.Check the condition of currentIndex == questions.length-1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).